# Reshape DataFrame from rows to columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, reshape

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like the following:

```
id, value
1, a
2, b
3, c
.
.
1000, fsdf
```

I would like to convert it to something like the following

```
id1, value1, id2, value2, ...... id5, value5
1,    a,      2,       b,          5,      e
6    
.
.
995,  .  .........................1000,    fsdf
```

Is there any way of doing it with pandas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.reshape`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) with [`shape`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.shape.html):

```
print df
   id value
0   1     a
1   2     b
2   3     c
3   4     d
4   5     e
5   6     f
6   7     g
7   8     h
8   9     i
9  10     j

print df.shape
(10, 2)

print df.values.reshape(df.shape[0] / 5, 10)
[[1L 'a' 2L 'b' 3L 'c' 4L 'd' 5L 'e']
 [6L 'f' 7L 'g' 8L 'h' 9L 'i' 10L 'j']]

#see http://stackoverflow.com/a/35511057/2901002
cols = ['{}{}'.format(x, y) for y in range(1, 6) for x in df.columns]
print cols
['id1', 'value1', 'id2', 'value2', 'id3', 'value3', 'id4', 'value4', 'id5', 'value5']

df = pd.DataFrame(df.values.reshape(df.shape[0] / 5, 10), columns=cols)
print df
  id1 value1 id2 value2 id3 value3 id4 value4 id5 value5
0   1      a   2      b   3      c   4      d   5      e
1   6      f   7      g   8      h   9      i  10      j
```

Comment: How does it works? Please dont forget accept solution, if was helpful. Thanks.